# How to know which rules were applied to predict one sample in trained decision tree model?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, decision-trees

I have trained Random Forest Regressor from sklearn. I am able to return text representation from each Decision Tree rule using tree.export_text (sklearn documentation [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.export_text.html)). But it shows rules for the model trained using the whole train set, rather than rules that were applied to predict values of given sample.

Of course, I can go through each rule and check if it fits to the data from my sample, but when the decision tree returns 150 rules, it becomes a really hard job.

I would be grateful for any ideas! Thank you :)

**Answer:**
Using a tree attributes and code from [sklearn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_unveil_tree_structure.html#decision-path) I was able to find rules that were used to predict a given sample.

Comment: `decision_path` gives the list of node indices the sample went through, then you can use the `tree_` attributes to connect that to features and thresholds, see https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_unveil_tree_structure.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-tree-plot-unveil-tree-structure-py. If I get some time I might flesh that out into an answer, but happy if anybody else gets there first.

Comment: @BenReiniger thank you. Using the link you posted I found out how the predicted value was created for the given sample. It was exactly what I needed

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer here.